# No top panel after installing Gnome

Tags: unity, gnome, compiz, window-manager

I recently removed Unity and installed gnome from the software center. There is no top bar/panel.
[image: my desktop]

Comment: It's 13.04 if that's of any help.

Answer (score 0):

Form the image that you included, it looks like you're running Cairo Dock, and probably have the top bar disabled.  Check your dock preferences, so you can enable the top bar.

Just right click on the bottom dock-->Cairo Dock-->Add.

Note: notice that there is no top bar.

[image]

Comment: That's kinda like it. I was kinda hoping to get the menu there though, not add a new dock. Y'know, the gnome top bar. The one that has the applications menu on the left, and the wireless, power, accessibility, etc, on the right. Have any tips?

Comment: The only way I know off, is to add another dock.  See [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wn4j0x532tkxhi9/2013-08-13_1058.png).